# Running count in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
id  orderId value
1   2B0B    100
2   2B0B    90
3   2B0B    80
4   2B0B    79
5   2B0B    65
6   2B0B    62
7   2B0B    50
8   2B0B    45
9   2B0B    30
10  2B0B    25
11  2B0B    10
12  2B0B    9
13  2B0B    0
14  2B0B    90
15  2B0B    60
16  2B0B    50
17  2B0B    30
```

From the above table, I am trying to count the no of rows in between 100 to 49and 50 to 24and 25 to 0.

Expecting OP:

```
Range count idBetween
100-49 6     1-6
50-24  3     7-9
25-0   4     10-13
100-49 2     14-15
50-24  2     16-17
```

Here idBetween is start and end of the id column like **group_concat(id)** in every range.

Is there anyway to achieve using mysql query?

Comment: Do you want only the count of the numbers in range, or do you also want the column with range of ID's which is I don't even know if possible?

Comment: You have completely omitted the description of idBetween field. Also, the ranges and your results are not consistent with each other. For example, record with id 10 does not seem to be counted in the 50-24 range, even though the value is 25. So, you have a lot more explaining to do.

Comment: also the ranges are kind of not logical 100-49 50-24 when the number is 50 does it mean it is included in both counts?

Comment: You're sure that you want overlapping ranges?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a virtual attribute representing each range. If the ranges were linear then you could do something like:

```
SELECT 10*(FLOOR(value/10)), COUNT(*), MIN(id), MAX(id)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY 10*(FLOOR(value/10));
```

But your ranges are not linear. Further they are NOT DISCRETE! Assuming that you really mean ranges of 0-24, 25-49, 50-99 then:

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN value>=100 THEN '100'
  WHEN VALUE BETWEEN 50 AND 99 then '50-99'
  WHEN VALUE BETWEEN 25 AND 49 THEN '25-49'
  WHEN VALUE BETWEEN 0 AND 24 THEN '0-24'
  ELSE 'ERROR'
 END AS bucket,
COUNT(*), MIN(id), MAX(id)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY CASE 
  WHEN value>=100 THEN '100'
  WHEN VALUE BETWEEN 50 AND 99 then '50-99'
  WHEN VALUE BETWEEN 25 AND 49 THEN '25-49'
  WHEN VALUE BETWEEN 0 AND 24 THEN '0-24'
  ELSE 'ERROR'
END
```

However your example output show that you want to report on runs of consecutive values within a range. "Consecutive" implies an order - although your input set is ordered by ID you should state what the required ordering is.

It is possible to do this in a MySQL query but the code will be too complex

- to write here
- to maintain

And would be more sensibly implemented in a procedural programming language.

Comment: With session variables you can take care of the islands. But the question is still unclear to me.

Comment: @Shadow 3: Feel free to share your solution.

Comment: (bearing in mind that this requires at least 2 state variables and the MySQL documentation does not define the order in which embedded assignments are carried out in non-procedural SQL).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution to the first part of the problem:

```
SELECT x.*
     , CASE WHEN @prev > value THEN @i:=@i + 1 ELSE @i:=@i END i
     , @prev:=value 
  FROM test x
     , (SELECT @prev:=null, @i:=0) vars 
 ORDER 
    BY id DESC;
```

The second part of the problem is unclear at present.